# How to make a function call using the control's ID and $ in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code .. I am not able to call the function on button click. Please help.
[ I don't wish to use onclick method in the input tag ]

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("btn").on("click",function(){
                 console.log("Clicked_btn");
        });

      // Also tried :

        $("btn").click(function(){
                 console.log("Clicked_btn");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Click to Submit" />
</body>
```

Both methods do not invoke the function.. where am I going wrong ?

Comment: add `#` before the selector

Comment: I am sorry .. I had that # in the code, I missed while typing it here on StackOverflow.. :(

Comment: I get this error in the firebug on firefox when I tried to debug : 

Error: http://localhost:8080/Testing_AjaxCall/jquery-1.10.2.min.js is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the document has loaded before running your javascript, otherwise jQuery won't be able to find the input element:

```
$(function(){

   $("#btn").click(function(){
      console.log("Clicked_btn");
   });

});
```

Comment: Thank you .. I had not used the ready function().
Now it works.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use the [`id selector`](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) properly and wrap the code inside of the document ready handler,

```
$(function(){
 $("#btn").on("click",function(){
    console.log("Clicked_btn");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also have

```
 $(document).on('click','#btn',function(){
       console.log("Clicked_btn");
 });
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JcbYh/)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, it should work:

```
  $(document).on('click', '#btn', function(){
             console.log("Clicked_btn");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to,this is more preferred.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function (){
 $("#btn").on("click",function(){
    console.log("Clicked_btn");
 });
});

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Click to Submit" />
</body>``
```